# How to append records to existing Power BI table using SSIS

Tags: ssis, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am looking to move records from an SQL Server database and append them to an existing table in Power BI.  I wanted to know if this is possible using SSIS and if there are any overviews or tutorials on how this would work?

Also, are their any other tools which would be better?  I have looked at data flows.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The important points here are: 1, you have an existing PowerBI report that's already connected to a data source & 2, you wish to add another data source.

PowerBI has built tools for doing that. Once your bring in the 2nd source (just click `Get Data` as normal), you can click `Transform Data` to start the `Power Query Editor` which will allow you to "clean up" or "transform" the incoming data so it fits in well with the existing data.

Since your data is unique to you, then there is no copy & paste answer I can provide. You'll have to **shape** the data yourself to get it into your existing report in a clean fashion. I recommend making a copy of your ***.pbix** file first as transforming data is a bit of learning experience. Just try to import a few times until you get the swing of it, then attack the real thing.

**DOCUMENTS, TUTORIALS, & EXAMPLES**

[This Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-shape-and-combine-data#combine-data)
discusses both **shaping** and **combining** data.

[This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/9sfCDCpWTfc)
shows how 2 data sources might be combined together.

[This forum response](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Append-vs-Merge-using-Power-Query/m-p/943950#M452363)
explains **merge** and **append** and also provides more links.

Some of the jargon has changed over the years, so when you research more just keep in mind that button names might be a bit different.

**SUMMARY**

In summary, SSIS should not be required. PBI has advanced data transforming & modeling tools to handle pretty much everything. Alternatively, perhaps consider making a totally separate **.pbix** file for the 2nd data source. It's much easier to combine the 2 reports on a single **Dashboard** later on.